# getting make file variables in a go package?

Tags: go, makefile

I have a variable `VERSION` in a make file that sets the version for binary at compile time using `-ldflags`

```
VERSION = $(strip $(TIMESTAMP))
LDFLAGS = -ldflags "-X main.buildTime $(BUILD_TIME) -X main.buildNumber $(VERSION)"
```

Now I want to get the VERSION in a package which is not `main` and print it. I tried bunch of options, but not able to make it work.

My question is how can I get it in the package and then print it to client at run time, such as `you are connected to app version 2.0`..??

Comment: You have to provide the version somehow. If it's not `package main`, then you need to import the package and read the variable.

Comment: so the ldflags are setting the variables in main package `main.buildTime` etc. and I can't import main, so I tried setting it with other package, but somehow still not working, I get empty string :(

Comment: If you're setting the variable in main, it only exists as you set it in the final binary -- so make the binary output the version with a special flag. As for "setting it with another package", you'll have to show an example because I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You mean, if I add another flag such as `-X xyz.buildVersion` in make file, then I should be able to access buildVersion in `xyz` package. I am doing that and then I have `var buildVersion string` in xyz package, but it is empty although I am doing `go install -ldflags myapp.go`

Comment: oh missed the "make the binary output the version with special flag" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory structure:

```
- main.go
- test/
  - test.go
```

**test.go**

```
package test

var Version = ""
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test.Version)
}
```

Finally, run:

```
go run -ldflags="-X test.Version 2.0.0" main.go
```

Outputs:

```
> 2.0.0
```

Since we can specify import path, we can set the value of a string everywhere, not only in main.

From go 1.5 up, syntax is changed to `importpath.name=string`.